# Reactive Cocoa 4.0 Concept

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

I'm currently working through trying to understand Reactive Cocoa 4 with Swift 2.0. I think I understand most of the core concepts but i'm wondering if anybody with more knowledge could provide an example of how to solve the following example contact list using ReactiveCocoa:

1. There is an array of contacts which are downloaded via an API and cached
2. The contacts are sorted into groups by surname alphabetically
3. The groups of contacts are represented in a UITableView as sections (letter) and rows
4. The first name and last name is represented in rows in the UITableViewCell in uppercase
5. When the data gets updated via an API (triggered by a timer) the UITableView is refreshed
6. When the UITableView is removed and returned to the screen the cached data is used until the timer is fired and the data refreshes again
7. A background change to a contact (first name change) gets updated to the UITableViewCell automatically

I think the key thing here which i'm struggling with is the memory management around disposing of the disposables, do I need to store these and when the UITableView is removed dispose of it? I'm concerned that i'll end up with a whole bunch of instance variables to store disposables, is this correct?

Comment: Use operators such as `takeUntil` instead of explicit disposing

Comment: I ran into all sorts of problems with how I wanted to use ReactiveCocoa, i'm probably not using it correctly to be fair especially when it comes to caching. Rather then fight with it and after deciding it was too complex to modify I rolled my own mini version last night which works how I wanted :)